Tracing deduplicated function invocations with OpenTelemetry
I have a job-queuing system where all jobs are identified by the hash of their arguments. This means that if three different functions all try to make a call with the same arguments, the call only happens once (even if the invocations are concurrent: a new call to a function already being run will wait for the existing instance to complete and get a copy of its return value; a call to a function with an argument set that was previously invoked successfully will retrieve its result from a datastore without running it at all).
This generally works well, but one thing I've sidestepped is how to make OpenTelemetry tracing work in this context.

We can't pass the traceparent as an argument into the queuing system, because this would mean that every call would be distinct and the point of the deduplication would be mooted.
We could have a second, non-deduplicated store where we track which callers have made the same request; but as far as I know, any span can only have one parent, so we could only use a single element from this store, and other calls that happened to lose the race wouldn't know what happened during invocation.

Does OpenTelemetry have facilities to allow this kind of case to be gracefully handled?

While this is generally a language-agnostic question, Python would be preferred for any concrete code examples.
